# Days Count using formula

Tags: excel, date, time, text-parsing

Someone helped me pull the number of days of this string:

2015-04-01 14:31:00 -- 2015-04-15 14:02:27

Using this formula

```
=IFERROR((((DATEVALUE((MID('Paste Sales Report'!P3,FIND("-- ",'Paste Sales Report'!P3)+3,10)))-DATEVALUE(LEFT('Paste Sales Report'!P3,10)))*24)+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT('Paste Sales Report'!P3,9))-TIMEVALUE(MID('Paste Sales Report'!P3,FIND(" ",'Paste Sales Report'!P3)+1,9)))/24,"0")
```

anyone is able to help with the slightly more complex (the quotes are part of the string):

```
 "Sales Report - agg-all-store - 86271 - 2015-02-20 09:45:40 - 2015-04-22 09:45:50”
```

Again I need to turn the data range in the string into a number of days.

Comment: What is this? Excel? SQL? Can you be more specific using your tags? I don't understand even how to evaluate this question :)
You may want to have a look at the SO Help Section in order to learn how you can help proper help from this community. Welcome aboard :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

> =LEFT(RIGHT('Paste Sales Report'!P3,20),19)-LEFT(RIGHT('Paste Sales Report'!P3,42),19)

That will give you a decimal number of days, 61.0001157 for your example, is that how you are displaying it or do you want to show days, hours, minutes?

That works if you have the date/time stamps consistently at the end of the string (apart from the final quote).

You don't really need to split time and date as per your original formula, you can subtract one whole time/date entity from the other to get a result in days. That's what this formula does.

Note: in the original formula find looks for a double hyphen but I only see single ones in your example. If that's a double hyphen between the time stamps then change 42 in formula to 43